# Does the first instance of a model have an id of 0 or 1?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm wondering if the very first instance of a model has an id of 0 or 1?

I'm interested in default functionality for PostgreSQL and SQLite.

Thanks!

Comment: That depends, strictly speaking, on the underlying database. For most databases it is `1`. It is an `AutoField`, and the ids are assigned by the database, in some databases, like PostgreSQL, you can provide it a different sequence, and thus dispatch `id`s in a totally different way. But it is typically a bad idea to "work with these ids". Personally I think it is better to see ids as "blackbox" identifiers, where the content/type/... is unknown.

Comment: Sorry. I should have been more clear. I'm interested in SQLLite and PostgreSQL databases. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both SQLite and PostgreSQL use 1 as the default starting point for auto-increment style indicies (assuming an increasing value).

From the [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) on autoincrement:

> If the table is initially empty, then a ROWID of 1 is used.

From the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-createsequence.html) on sequences:

> The optional clause `MINVALUE minvalue` determines the minimum value a sequence can generate. If this clause is not supplied or `NO MINVALUE` is specified, then defaults will be used. The defaults are `1` and `-2^63 - 1` for ascending and descending sequences, respectively.